# JPA Entity from Hibernate to EclipseLink

Tags: java, hibernate, eclipselink

Sorry for my English

I have some problems with mapping entity in EclipseLink JPA. 
I have some entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TSENSOR")
@Cacheable
public class Sensor extends Model implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    SensorIdentifier key;
    @Column(name = "CDESCRIPTION", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    String description;
    @Column(name = "CTYPE")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    SensorType type;

    ...

}


@Embeddable
public class SensorIdentifier extends DeviceIdentifier {
    @Column(name = "PNUM")
    byte num;

    ...

}

@Embeddable
@MappedSuperclass
public class DeviceIdentifier extends Model implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "PSYSTEM", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    String systemName;
    @Column(name="PDEVICEID")
    int id;
    @Column(name="PDEVICESUBID")
    short subId;

    ...

}
```

On server-side this entity mapped in Hibernate JPA and work excelent. But on client i need mapped this entity in EclipseLink JPA (I work with Eclipse RCP 4.x and Gemini DI), and i had this exception:

> Exception [EclipseLink-46] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception
>   Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the
>   primary key field [TSENSOR.PSYSTEM]. Descriptor:
>   RelationalDescriptor(watchdog.core.client.model.Sensor -->
>   [DatabaseTable(TSENSOR)])

This problem only with entity contains EmbeddedId

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that you should have one mapping for

```
@Column(name = "PSYSTEM", insertable = false, updatable = false)
String systemName;
```

that can be written to. (non-read-only)
So one other mapping for PSYSTEM with insertable or updatable on true.